# Using Uitextfield for user input, trying to convert to int, if not int then return 0

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am building a practice app to add user inputs in an app. I have a few user defaults from a UITextfield, but when I run my function it does not work when I a missing an input, bc it does not recognize an empty textfield as an integer. I am trying to create an if statement that if = " " then return INT(0) else the INT(user default).

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(hole1.text, forKey: "hole1enter")}

@IBAction func Total(_ sender: Any) {
     let h1:String = hole1.text! {
         if h1 == " " {
           print(0)
         } else {
             print(Int(h1))
         }
  }
```

I have tried a bunch of attempts, but I keep getting errors, I am just getting started with swift. Do you all have any good literature on a better way to understand converting strings, text, ints or functions themselves? In the end I want to be able to sum the total of all the userdefault inputs

Comment: You can just make the keyboard a number pad if you expect only numbers as an output

Comment: The `NumberFormatter` class converts between localized strings and numeric values. Create an instance and then use the `number(String)` function to convert from a localized string to a number (object). For more complicated parsing (which I don't think you need here), there is the `Scanner` class.

Answer (score 2):

Not all `String`s can be represented as an `Int`, so you need to check if the return value of the failable `Int` initializer returns `nil` or not. You can simply supply a default value as 0.

You can safely force-unwrap `UITextField`s `text` property, because it is documented to be always non-nil.

```
@IBAction func total(_ sender: Any) {
    let intValue = Int(hole1.text!) ?? 0
    print(intValue)
}
```

You should also conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lowerCamelCase for function and variable names (`total`).

Answer (score 1):

First problem: you should check if `text` property is empty `String`, so you need to use `""` not string with whitespace <strike>`if h1 == " "`</strike> (you can also use designed `isEmpty` property which returns `true` if string is `""`).

Next, converting from `String` to `Int` can fail so it returns optional. You can use optional-binding or setting default value for safely assigning value from value returned from initialization

```
@IBAction func Total(_ sender: Any) {

    let h1 = hole1.text!

    if h1.isEmpty {
        print(0)
    } else {
        let int = Int(h1) ?? 0
        print(int)
    }
}
```

which can be shorten just to this

```
@IBAction func Total(_ sender: Any) {
    let int = Int(hole1.text!) ?? 0
    print(int)
}
```

since if `text` is empty string, `Int` can't be constructed

---

Last problem which I see is that you're saving optional `String?` to `UserDefaults`. Don't do that, safely force-unwrap it using exclamation mark since `text` property of `UITextField` is never `nil`

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(hole1.text!, forKey: "hole1enter")
}
```